# Minimized window needs two clicks to restore

Tags: winforms

I have a very strange problem with my winforms form.
It's not easy to explain but i will try:

If i minimize my form with the minimize button it will take two clicks (minimum) on the taskbar icon to restore it. The first click seams to do absolutly nothing. There is no event (Resize, SizeChanged, ...) fired.

If i minimize the form by clicking on the taskbar icon it will take only one click to restore it, like i would expect it.

I have no idea why this behavior is like it is.

The very strange part is, that if any other application / folder / ... is open and shown it take one click to restore my form even the form is minimized with the minimize button. On minimize, the other application get the focus. This seams to be enough for my form to restore with one click only.

If every other application is minimized or if my application is the only one which is running it takes two or more clicks to restore.

Why? Hope anybody can help me. I have no idea.

Comment: Are you performing all tasks on main thread?

Comment: This should be a bugfix in a very huge software so your question is not so easy to answer for me, but as far as i know, yes. The problem is reproducible directly after the start.

Comment: does the problem exists immediately after you start the application or it begins acting this way after a while? Does the problem exists after an OS  restart?

Comment: The problem exists immediately after the start and for all the time the application is running. Also after an OS restart.

Comment: And does the problem exists on all machines?

Comment: Yes, the problem exists on all machines.

Comment: Please, add a random button on screen. And add this action to it: 
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; Check if it needs double or single click

Comment: To minimize a single click is enough

Comment: So if you add the button, the behavior is normal? The problem os just with the taskbar? Confirm it?

Comment: If you alt tab to the app, does it go instant?

Comment: The button minimize the dialog but the problem is the same like it woulde be if i minimize it with the normal minimize button (top right).

Comment: ALT+TAB doesn't work, too. The dialog could not be opened / restored with ALT+TAB.

Comment: I just noticed that the language chooser in the taskbar hides after the first click. After the second click - when the dialog opens - the language chooser is back again, too o_O If i click, after the first click on my application, directly on the taskbar the language chooser comes back, too, but then the next (second) click on my application is like the first, i happens nothing o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to a UI component that You are populating, or invoking it at runtime. It is quite monkey job, but what you can do to find what is hanging is comment some UI components, and try to see if the problem persists.

Usually this happens because the Main UI Thread when you are running STA, is waiting for a focus, or for an user action. Since you double focus it, it might proceed.

Comment: This is what i've done to locate the bug. It was strange code in the activation event.

Comment: Had same issue with Powershell/WPF forms, custom minimize button that set $Window.WindowState='Minimized' putting $Window.Activate() | Out-Null on the next line solved the issue. Single click on the taskbar is now working to restore. +1